# How to update the size of the parent widget from the size of the children in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, parent-child

This snippet that runs on Kivy for Python draws some rectangles (Boxes) as child widgets of a parent one (RootWidget).

By pressing ALT + D you create another box (added to the RootWidget).

I'm trying to implement a touch and drag behavior on the parent widget so that it moves all the child boxes together when they are dragged with the mouse.

However, the on_touch_down method (see self.collide_point(*touch.pos)) just gets the position of the original child widget (the one created by default) but not of the newly created ones.

Why? Is there a way to update the size of the parent so that it gets grabbed when a box other than the first is touched?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Color, Rectangle, Line
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty

from random import randint


Builder.load_string('''


<Box>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: .1, .1, 1, .9
        Line:
            width: 2.
            rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


''')


class Tree(Widget):
    pass

class Node(Widget):
    pass

class Box(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Box, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size = [500, 300]
        self.height = self.size[1]
        self.width = self.size[0]        
        self.pos = [500,200]

        # bind change of pos to redraw
        self.bind(pos=self.redraw, size=self.redraw)

    def redraw(self, *args):
        # compute head and sisters' positions
        self.x = self.pos[0]
        self.y = self.pos[1]
        #self.height = self.size[0]
        #self.width = self.size[1]        

class Branches(Widget):
    pass

class Terbranch(Widget):
    pass





class RootWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(2):
            self.add_widget(Box())

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

        self.bind(pos=self.redraw, size=self.redraw)

    def redraw (self, *args):
        pass


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            # if the touch collides with our widget, let's grab it
            touch.grab(self)           
            #print ('touched')
            # and accept the touch.
            return True

        return super(RootWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # check if it's a grabbed touch event
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            # don't forget to ungrab ourself, or you might have side effects
            touch.ungrab(self)
            # and accept the last up
            return True

        return super(RootWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        # check if it's a grabbed touch event
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            #self.pos = touch.pos
            self.pos[0] +=  touch.dx
            self.pos[1] +=  touch.dy

            #redraw moved children
            for child in self.children:
                child.pos[0] +=  touch.dx
                child.pos[1] +=  touch.dy
                child.redraw()
        # and accept the last move
            return True

        return super(RootWidget, self).on_touch_move(touch)



    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        #print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
        #print(' - text is %r' % text)
        #print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        elif keycode[1] == 'd' and modifiers[0] == 'alt':
            newbox = Box()
            self.add_widget(newbox)

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True

    def update(self, dt):

        pass





class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        rw = RootWidget()
        #Clock.schedule_interval(rw.update, 0.2)
        return rw


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but in your `on_touch_move` method you are moving all the child `Box` instances. But you are also changing the `pos` of the `RootWidget` itself. Since the `RootWidget` is the root window of the `App`, changing its `pos` property doesn't have any visual effect. However, that change affects the `self.collide_point` method (it uses `pos` and `size` to check for collision). So, if I understand your question, you just need to eliminate changing the `pos` of the `RootWidget`:

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    # check if it's a grabbed touch event
    if touch.grab_current is self:
        #self.pos = touch.pos

        # comment out the next two lines
        #self.pos[0] +=  touch.dx
        #self.pos[1] +=  touch.dy

        #redraw moved children
        for child in self.children:
            child.pos[0] +=  touch.dx
            child.pos[1] +=  touch.dy
            child.redraw()
    # and accept the last move
        return True
```

Comment: the problem is not about the pos of the RootWidget but its size that gets computed by the collision. The collision works right picking the Bounding Box of the initial child widget included in the RootWidget, but not of the other newly created boxes

Comment: I guess it' snot possible using the predefined touch behaviour.
What I'll try to do is to compute the touch on each box, and percolate up the behavior to all the children of the parent (all the boxes)

Comment: The collision does not compute a size, it uses the existing position and size of the `RootWidget` to check for collision. Changing the `pos` property of the `RootWidget` changes that calculation and makes it incorrect. Try your code with my suggested change.